# Winter Bash hat questions on Meta Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, scope, winter-bash

I saw a few Winter Bash hat questions on the Meta Stack Overflow. Should these questions be moved to the Meta Meta? It seems like they are more on topic here because hats are available across all sites in the SE network.

Examples:

- [What would happen if someone collected all the hats?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340343/what-would-happen-if-someone-collected-all-the-hats)
- [My Hats disappeared!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339833/my-hats-disappeared)

Answer (score 13):

[Users Can Report Bugs On Whatever Child Meta Site Suits Them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250152/1990216)

> It's fine if users post bug reports, requests for support or feature requests here on MSO, there's no need to close them as off-topic. Please, don't do that, it's off-putting and rude.

Questions about hats *may* (it's debatable) be "more" on-topic here but they're still on-topic on per-site metas and there's no reason for them to be *moved* here. The question will be seen just as much on per-site metas.

You can point out that it's an *option* to post here (a lot of users won't know that), but don't push people from place to place, it's not necessary and frustrating.

Comment: What happens if you post a question about hats that has already been asked on MSO on the meta?

Comment: More than likely it just gets answered again, but there's nothing inherently wrong with that. The existing Q&A can be linked to in the newer answer if needed. As the linked MSO question says a mod can handle migrating the question if it is needed, but there's no real reason to in most cases

Comment: I think I have cross linked more Winter Bash questions between MSO and MSE than I have hats.

Comment: @Glorfindel maybe you should suggest a new hat for cross-linking hat questions ;)